# Alpha Vantage - Isolate Stock Price

Tags: python-3.x, alpha, alpha-vantage

Using Python I can access most of the Alpha Vantage APIs and get the results either as a tuple or a dict.  What I want is just the stock price at a point in time.  With "global quote", for example, I get all the data but cannot parse or divide the tuple / dict into the individual items.

Has anyone done this? I'd be grateful to see the code.

The API returns the following data; it is type `dict` with len `1`. What I need is the price (108.29) in a normal floating point variable.

```
 (' data ', {u'Global Quote': {u'05. price': u'108.2900', u'08. previous close': u'107.2800', u'10. change percent': u'0.9415%', u'03. high': u'108.8800', u'07. latest trading day': u'2018-11-16', '}})
```

Comment: Have you read up on how to use tuples and dictionaries in Python? What's the specific problem you're having accessing the data you need?

Comment: I sure have.  The API returns the following data; it is type 'dict' with len '1'.  What I need is the price (108.29)  in a normal floating point variable.                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                       
 (' data ', {u'Global Quote': {u'05. price': u'108.2900', u'08. previous close': u'107.2800', u'10. change percent': u'0.9415%', u'03. high': u'108.8800', u'07. latest trading day': u'2018-11-16', '}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you have given appears to have a slight problem at the end (there is a trailing comma and open quote). Assuming that the actual data does not have this problem, you could extract the price into a float variable as follows:

```
data = (' data ', {u'Global Quote': {u'05. price': u'108.2900', u'08. previous close': u'107.2800', u'10. change percent': u'0.9415%', u'03. high': u'108.8800', u'07. latest trading day': u'2018-11-16'}})
price = float(data[1]['Global Quote']['05. price'])
print(price)
```

This would display the price as:

```
108.29
```

The API appears to be returing a tuple which consists of the word data and then a dictionary holding all the values. So first use `[1]` to access the dictionary. The `Global Quote` entry itself is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I hadn't considered that as a possibility, i.e., a dict within a tuple.  I am new to both Linux and Python so I guess that's kind of an amateur error.  Nevertheless, I really appreciate the time taken to respond.  I hope to pay that back in the near future.

Just BTW, I notice w/Python if I code something wrong I sometimes don't get an error - exactly.  For example, if I issue a print statement to debug and do not reference the above item correctly, the print command doesn't execute but I do not get an error code.  In fact, code following the offensive print statement might also not execute; I might simply go to EOJ.  Does that make sense?  NB - I haven't compiled yet; still running in interpretive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Hey below is a function I wrote to easily extract historical stock prices from Alpha Vantage. All you have to do is plug in your symbol and token. If you want the stock price for a specific day, then you will need to filter for that day in the result dataframe. For more functions on extracting Alpha Vantage data, feel free to check out my link: https://github.com/hklchung/StockPricePredictor/blob/master/2020/alphavantage_funcs.py.

```
def request_stock_price_hist(symbol, token, sample = False):
    if sample == False:
        q_string = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol={}&outputsize=full&apikey={}'
    else:
        q_string = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol={}&apikey={}'

    print("Retrieving stock price data from Alpha Vantage (This may take a while)...")
    r = requests.get(q_string.format(symbol, token))
    print("Data has been successfully downloaded...")
    date = []
    colnames = list(range(0, 7))
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colnames)
    print("Sorting the retrieved data into a dataframe...")
    for i in tqdm(r.json()['Time Series (Daily)'].keys()):
        date.append(i)
        row = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json()['Time Series (Daily)'][i], orient='index').reset_index().T[1:]
        df = pd.concat([df, row], ignore_index=True)
    df.columns = ["open", "high", "low", "close", "adjusted close", "volume", "dividend amount", "split cf"]
    df['date'] = date
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to get the price data is this

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime as dt
import requests
import os
import json

stock_ticker="TSLA"
apikey=""
ts = TimeSeries (key=apikey, output_format = "pandas")



    ### STOCK TIME SERIES > DAILY ADJUSTED ###
        # Date / Open / High / Low / Close / Adjusted Close / Volume / Dividend / Split
data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=stock_ticker, outputsize ='full')
        # data_daily['column name'][row number]
data_daily_lastOpenPrice = data_daily['1. open'][0]
data_daily_lastHighPrice = data_daily['2. high'][0]
data_daily_lastLowPrice = data_daily['3. low'][0]
data_daily_lastAdjustedClosingPrice = data_daily['5. adjusted close'][0]
data_daily_lastTradingVolume = data_daily['6. volume'][0]
data_daily_lastDividendAmount = data_daily['7. dividend amount'][0]
```